# how to reveal an object's attributes in Python?

Tags: python

Is there any method to let me know  the values of an object's attributes?
For example, 
`info = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')`
I wanna know all the attributes' values of info. Maybe I don't know what are the attributes the info has. And str() or list() can not give me the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the names of object's attributes, use `dir(obj)`. To get their values, use `getattr(obj, attr_name)`. You could print all the attributes and their values like so:

```
for attr in dir(obj):
    print(attr, getattr(obj, attr))
```

If you don't need the built-in attributes, such as `__str__` etc, you can simply use `obj.__dict__`, which returns a dictionary of object's attributes and their values.

```
for k in obj.__dict__:
    print(k, obj.__dict__[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vars(info)` or `info.__dict__`. It will return the object's namespace as a dictionary in the attribute_name:value format.

Comment: @Wessie `dir(info)` would only list the attribute names, OP here is asking for values of attributes.

Comment: I get the idea of avoiding to access private attributes. Hence `vars(info)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's [dir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir). dir(info) will return all the valid attributes for the object info.

```
info = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print dir(info)
```

Comment: dir(info) will provide attribute names, OP is asking for values of attributes.

Comment: Ya. I didn't notice it @sidi. You are right. We can use vars(info) or info.__dict__ as sidi mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `dir()`:

```
dir(info)
```

[dir() man](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

Answer (score 0):

All methods using dir() or looking at **dict** are bascially a no go.

Better check

```
obj.__class__
```

and

```
obj.__class__.__bases__
```

in order to get an idea what the object really is.

Then you should check the offial API documentation of the module.

Methods and data might be private and are in general not for public consumption unless stated otherwise by the documentation.